# Record video while playing TV on Jio Phone

Tags: ios, video, iphone

I connect my iPhone to the AUX cable in my car and play TV. This one time I wanted to video record, but when I switch to the video camera, it turns my TV off.

Is there anyway to record video on iPhone 6 **while** playing TV, so that the TV shows is in the video?

Comment: In short: without jailbreak? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app called "Jamcam" is the only way I've found to do it, might be better options out there but I don't know them, hope his helped (:

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Record and Listen](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/record-and-listen/id1023640638?mt=8). Jamcam is great, but only records videos for up to 15 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I helped develop [this iPhone app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/mideo-video-listen-to-music/id1358135284) just for this purpose. It is a video recorder that won't pause your music.

Answer (score 2):

Snapchat does. you can only make 10 second videos but its still plays in the background your voice and whatever you're playing from your phone

Comment: Thanks Whitni and welcome to S.E. I just enjoyed your Musiq cover on youtube, good stuff! I think you might like these communities: http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/ and http://music.stackexchange.com/ : )

Answer (score 1):

Hey there’s a possible way to do that its so simple without any jailbreak or anything .. everyone has whatsapp it does the same thing what you are asking for just creat group on whatsapp add your any friend and then go and remove him or her now you can go to now open camera from that group record a unlimited video with background music and sent it in group and save it

Answer (score -3):

WhatsApp that’s what I use I just send to my old phone number find something like that or just send to a friend who doesn’t Mind getting random vids from you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Would you mind [edit]ing your answer into a better shape? I think your solution might work, but right now it's hard to tell.