# Playing Music while recording?

Tags: music, ios, camera, cydia, tweaks

So I'm having the issue; How can I play music on iOS 7 while recording?

I've seen [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168694/record-video-while-playing-music) post but "JamCam" isn't something I'm interested in.

Is there a Cydia tweak which allows this? I'm surprised I can't find it on Google!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this app: [Record And Listen](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/record-and-listen/id1023640638?mt=8)

This app solves the problem of not being able to record a video while playing music from your library. You choose a song and record a video which is automatically saved to your phone. This app is great for taking dance videos, or if you just want to continue playing your music while taking a video. Price is 0.99$.

Answer (score -2):

You can also try [Relish - Record, Listen, Shine](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/relish-record-listen-shine/id1023640638?mt=8)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofdy-CEDsmA