# Can Camera+ 2 iPhone app record video while playing music?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, spotify

I'm wondering if [Camera+ 2 app](https://camera.plus) support recording video while playing music (via Spotify) in the background?

If not, what app could be used instead?

Comment: Have you tried to do this in real time?

Comment: What do you mean under "in real time"? May be you are missing a bit of context: I'm just deciding, which app I could use for that. I have not tried Camera+ 2 yet.

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179077/279727)?

Comment: What I mean by 'in real time' is; have you actually tried _using_ the app Camera+ 2 to see if it works the way you want it to?

Comment: @NimeshNeema - Another answer to that question you link to states that it records videos up to 15 seconds duration. That seems rather short, but Ilya Ananyev does not specify the length of the videos he wants to make.

Comment: @IconDaemon I've written in my previous comment, that I had not used it previously. Now I've bought the app, but there is no video record function at all, so my question didn't help me to avoid wasting money...

Answer (score 2):

I've got an answer for the first part of the question: Camera+ 2 doesn't have record video function. It's only to make photos.

Answer (score 1):

[Media Monster](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/media-monster-pro-tools/id876314777?mt=8) is also an alternate iPhone/iPad app that lets you record videos while playing music. You can use Spotify, Apple music, import raw audio files and plays them and many more platforms.

Answer (score 0):

[JamCam](http://www.jamcam.co) is an iPhone app which allows recording video, without stopping the music.

Comment: How can I use this app for the use case, I've described? Could you please explain it step by step.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. Just install the app from the App Store (available for free) and you can try out yourself.

Comment: I've installed it. I've started playing music from another app - spotify. I've opened JamCam app. There are 6 buttons and menu. What should I do to record video without stopping music now?